# How to extract contents from SSGTM using variable

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side, facebook-conversions-api

currently, I have this query parameter from a server side GTM that I want to extract the value. the parameter is like this. `parameter=[{id: "abcd", quantity: 1}]`. So I want to extract the vale of this parameter. When I use a an `"Event data"` variable, I get `[object object]`, but I want to get something like `{id: "abcd", quantity: 1}` or better still, how can I extract the contents of this parameter. I also used a community template *"extract from JSON"* and it still did not work.

I tried to use a community template *"extract from JSON"* and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter value is parameter=[{id: "abcd", quantity: 1}], then you can get it with the Event Data Variable. You can set:

```
parameter.0
```

To get a specific property you can use (e.g. for id):

```
parameter.0.id
```